# How can I import the sequential tsp Solution as a data file and use Optaplanner to evaluate which constraints the Solution violates?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Now I have established my own model with reference to the tsp problem, which is the same as the planning sequence of the tsp.
But we all know that the tsp problem is to find the shortest path solution for us after inputting the data set. Now I want to use Optaplanner to evaluate my existing solution. This solution is actually a data set with order (such as visit1-visit4-visit2-······-visit38).
I want to know me by looking at the violation of constraints Is the existing solution feasible, then **how do I import the ordered data**? Can it be achieved by assigning a value to the “previousStandstill” property of Visit?

Answer (score 0):

`ScoreManager` is ideal to calculate the score of a solution without solving it and also explain it. [See docs.](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#explainingTheScore)

```
ScoreManager<CloudBalance, HardSoftScore> scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
System.out.println(scoreManager.explainScore(solution));
```

> how do I import the ordered data? Can it be achieved by assigning a value to the “previousStandstill” property of Visit?

Yes. If there shadow variables, you also need to make sure those are set correctly. See `TspImporter` in optaplanner-examples.